# Formatting bug when adding html anchor tag to string

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I'm dealing with a strange formatting bug I can't figure out. With the help of some others, I have a small function that replaces all the @[user] in a string with a link to the actual twitter user. Its working pretty well, but once I add it to my webpage it starts to freak out a little bit.

Heres an example of the string.

```
If you want these foams Ima give you the chrome <a href="https://twitter.com/WillThaRapper" target="_blank">@WillThaRapper</a>
```

However, once I append it to a `<p>` element to display on the page, it looks like this.

```
If you want these foams Ima give you the chrome &lt;a href&#x3D;&quot;https:&#x2F;&#x2F;twitter.com&#x2F;WillThaRapper&quot; target&#x3D;&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;@WillThaRapper&lt;&#x2F;a&gt;
```

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring this one out.

Comment: Where is the code which append the string in `p`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you're adding a string of HTML entities to your HTML. To add actual HTML you can use a `DOMParser` to convert the entities to HTML which can be rendered on the DOM:

```js
const decodeEntities = str => {
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
  return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}

// input = the text you want to append to the page
const input = "If you want these foams Ima give you the chrome &lt;a href&#x3D;&quot;https:&#x2F;&#x2F;twitter.com&#x2F;WillThaRapper&quot; target&#x3D;&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;@WillThaRapper&lt;&#x2F;a&gt";

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += decodeEntities(input);
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```